# An fpqc morphism is a "quotient" morphism (as a continuous map between topological spaces)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a faithfully flat quasi-compact morphism.
Then for a subset $V \subseteq Y$, $V$ is open in $Y$ iff $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$?

I know this is EGA IV2 2.3.12.
But its proof is very complicated for me.
(I'm not familiar with pro-constructibility.)
So are there other good proofs of it or its references?

Thank you very much!

Comment: See also Stacks Project [Tag 02JY](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02JY).

Comment: @user2831784 Thank you very much!! This is exactly what I want!